# Как переписать цикл, чтобы сделать шаг 0.01?

Tags: python, математика, for

```
x=0
N=5
sum1=0
for x in range(-math.pi,math.pi,0.01):
    k=1
    for k in range(N+1):
        sum1+=(np.sign((2*k-1)*x))/(2*k-1)
    sum1=sum1*(4/math.pi)
```

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 print(type(x))
>         3 sum1=0
>   ----> 4 for x in range(-math.pi,math.pi,0.01):
>         5     k=1
>         6     for k in range(N+1):
>
> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы вам не использовать модуль Numpy более широко?

```
x=0
N=5
sum1=0
for x in np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.01):
    for k in range(1, N+1):
        sum1+=(np.sign((2*k-1)*x))/(2*k-1)*(4/np.pi)
    sum1=sum1*(4/np.pi)
```

---

```
In [154]: print(sum1)
-1.0326167037008748e+67
```

PS судя по результату, стремящемуся к минус бесконечности, у вас ошибка в формуле.

PPS скорее всего формулу можно реализовать без циклов, используя векторизированные Numpy функции, но для этого понадобится более подробное описание формулы...

Comment: MaxU, в формуле не может быть ошибки, это ряд Фурье к sgn(x)

Comment: @steam-ilka в формуле может и нет ошибки, а в вашем коде может быть и есть. Покажите формулу

Comment: Да, вы правы, ошибка все таки была. Преподаватель неверно выписал формулу

Answer (score 5):

Range не принимает float аргументы. Вам придется цикл сделать иначе

```
x = -math.pi
while x < math.pi :
     x+= 0.01
```