# Ошибка TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer в range

Tags: python, type-error, range

Не понимаю кое-чего. Вот хочу просто вывести корень из `a` (код внизу):

```
def root(a):
    s=()
    for i in range(int(a),int(-a),0.0000001):
        x=a/i
        if x==i: s.append(x)
        else: continue
    return s
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    print(Math.operation.root(2)
  File "D:\Pashka2\Programme\Python\Math.py", line 40, in root
    for i in range(int(a),int(-a),0.0000001):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Почему возникает это исключение, и как мне исправить ошибку?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ага, а как же тогда?

Comment: Значит нужно использовать frange, так?

Comment: А нет, не работает.  А что же тогда?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как переписать цикл, чтобы сделать шаг 0.01?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1030888/1365)

Comment: @insolor спасибо, не заметил `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range` не работает с дробными параметрами, только с целочисленными. Как вариант, можно реализовать свой `range`, который будет уметь работать с `float`, например:

```
def frange(x, y, jump):
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += jump


step = 0.000001


def root(a):
    s = []
    for i in frange(-a, a, step):
        x = a/i
        if abs(x - i) < step:
            s.append(x)
            # Для более точного результата можно заменить на s.append((x+i)/2)

    return s


print(root(4))
```

Функция `frange` взята из этого ответа: [range() for floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7267280/4752653) [@kichik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492773) (перечеркнутый пример кода в начале ответа)

Вывод:

```
[-2.000000000279556, 1.9999999998691407]
```

C `s.append((x+i)/2)`:

```
[-2.0, 2.0]
```

Обратите внимание, что я заменил проверку на точное равенство на приблизительное
( `|x-i| < step`, т.е. разница между x и i по модулю меньше шага), иначе будет возвращаться пустой список.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Попробовал и заработало! Да. конечно, из-за большого цикла даже квадратный корень 4-х долго работал, но мне удалось чуток скоротить время с помощью `else: continue`. Работает теперь от двух до пяти секунд. Ну хотя бы что-то :-)

Comment: @PythonWeb, есть более быстрые способы нахождения корней: например метод деления пополам, метод секущих, метод касательных. Такими методами можно найти один из корней, потом зная что второй корень такой же, но с противоположным знаком - добавить в список решений и его.